# How to make a button change another button's title on a different view controller

Tags: ios, button, viewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to have a button send it's title to a new view controller, and the have a button on the new view controller have it's title set to the original button title.

I know how to do this on one view controller:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        buttonOne.setTitle("Hello", for: .normal)
        buttonTwo.setTitle("Hi there", for: .normal)
```

But not on another...

I thought maybe to use

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let sendTitle = segue.destination as! ViewControllerTwo
    sendTitle.notesent = sender as! String
```

but I get an error saying that the button can't be translated into a string, which makes sense to me, but I'm not sure how to target the string that is the button's title...

Thanks very much for any assistance!

Comment: do THIS-: if let buttonTitle = sender.title(for: .normal) {
    print(buttonTitle)
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it appears that you just wondering how to get a title from the button.

In your code you have to exchange `sender as! String` with

```
(sender as! UIButton).title(for: .normal)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Perfect. I needed to add an "!" after your code but it solved my problem. Thanks for answering my first question on stack!